# Correct form of this sentence

Tags: noun-phrases

What would be the correct form of the verb in this sentence? They all have a noun clause a the subject followed by *to be*.

> What you can do is **playing with them**.

> What you can do is **to play with them**.

> What you can do is **play with them**.

I always thought the first two are grammatical as it stands as a noun (object of the sentence), so it should be a gerund or infinitive.
But recently I have encountered some instances of the third case. I also looked some similar structures up on corpus and found similar instances:

> What you can do is **take** seeds from the crop that the seeds grew and then use them. (independent.co.uk)

> What you can do is **assess** the risks and hazards and set up ways of reducing risk. (guardian.co.uk)

If the third one, using *bare infinitive*, is syntactically correct, how do you justify it? Is it considered an adjective of sorts here?

Comment: The subject, "what you can do" is not a clause but a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction. The non-finite _play_ clause is in predicative complement function. Where the subject NP contains _do_ in a relative clause, both a _to_ infinitival and a bare one are possible, thus your 2nd and 3rd examples are both fine. Gerund-participial (_ing_) clauses can function as predicative complements, but not where the subject is a relative construction. Your first example is thus ungrammatical.

Comment: I'd compare your examples to *What you can do is **this:** play with them, peel them, then chop and fry.*